# Python query wrong output

Tags: python, sql, flask, kivy

I had a query that should return all permittedUserId when userId matched with what was supplied my the user. I wanted to use the result of the query for a different query and noticed I kept getting the same output.

```html
sql = "SELECT permittedUserId FROM PermittedSharedUSer WHERE PermittedSharedUSer.userId = %s"
```

Here is what the table looks like

[image]

Why do I get this output?

```
[{'num': 3}, {'num': 3}, {'num': 3}, {'num': 3}]
```

The output I want should be number 7,6,2,3, not 3,3,3,3

Here's the whole code:

```css
self.ensureConnected()
        applicationUser = (content['userID'], )
        sql = "SELECT permitedUserId FROM PermittedSharedUSer WHERE PermittedSharedUSer.userId = %s"
        crows = self.cursor.execute(sql, applicationUser)
        result = self.cursor.fetchall()
        
        if(len(result) > 0 ):
            d = collections.OrderedDict()
            objects_list = []
            for row in result:
                d['num'] = row[0]
                #sqlname = "SELECT name , username FROM Users WHERE Users.id=%s"
                #valname = (row[0],)
                #self.cursor.execute(sqlname,valname)
                #resultName = self.cursor.fetchall()
                #for row2 in resultName:
                #    d['name'] = row2[0]
                #    d['username'] = row2[1]
                objects_list.append(d)
            return (json.dumps(dict(data = objects_list), default=str), 200)   
        elif(crows ==None):
            return (json.dumps(dict(data = "empty")), 200)
```

Comment: Please add your code and output as text, not as images.

Comment: You are operating on four references to the same dictionary. Create a new dict on every iteration.

Comment: How do I do that exactly? Because I would like to group them as a whole in one dict at the end of the day.

Comment: If. `print(result)` shows the correct values, then the error is on the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample table which I created in SQL

[image]

and the code to fetch the data from it

```
import mysql.connector
db = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='5548',database='test')
cursor =db.cursor()
n='1'
cursor.execute("select permission from test where userid = %s",(n,))
v = cursor.fetchall()
for i in v:
    print(i[0],end=" ")
```

and the output is

```
7 6 2 4
```

Hence, the way you are establishing the connection and retrieving the data is fine.

Looking at the `for` loop - I can see the probable error

```
objects_list.append(d)
```

should be

```
objects_list.append(d['num'])
```

The code should look like this

```
applicationUser = (content['userID'], )
sql = "SELECT permitedUserId FROM PermittedSharedUSer WHERE PermittedSharedUSer.userId = %s"
crows = self.cursor.execute(sql, applicationUser)
result = self.cursor.fetchall()
if(len(result) > 0 ):
    d = collections.OrderedDict()
    objects_list = []
    for row in result:
        d['num'] = row[0]
        #sqlname = "SELECT name , username FROM Users WHERE Users.id=%s"
        #valname = (row[0],)
        #self.cursor.execute(sqlname,valname)
        #resultName = self.cursor.fetchall()
        #for row2 in resultName:
        #    d['name'] = row2[0]
        #    d['username'] = row2[1]
        objects_list.append(d['num'])
```

Comment: You were right  the problem came from objects_list.append(d)

Comment: Great! I'm glad I was able to assist you